# Java library for coordinate conversions

Tags: java

I'm in need of a library which supports the following conversions:

- Lat/Lon Degrees, Minutes, Seconds to Decimal Degrees
- MGRS to Lat/Lon Decimal Degrees

I've found a package in Openmap.jar which supports this, but I'd prefer to not add such a large dependency to my application (~3.6MB jar).  Has anyone had experience with repackaging this jar or another library which provides the same support?

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about output JAR size, [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net) is what I use -- it eliminates bits of libraries that you're not using quite effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [PROJ.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) ([Java Map Projection Library](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/)) or [Java Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm), both provide very good for 2D spatial operations.